# Добавление дополнительные данных в таблицу при выборе конкретного пункта <select>

Tags: php, mysql

Есть форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней 4 `<select>` у каждого из которых 2 пункта (вкл., выкл.). При добавлении пользователя *включаться будет только один из четырех*.

Выглядят они вот так:

```
<select size=1 name=pay>
    <option value="Включен">Включен</option>
    <option value="Выключен">Выключен</option>
</select>
```

Поле `Index2` я заполняю вручную и отправляю в базу. **Но нужно сделать так, чтобы при выборе определенного `<select>`, в базу автоматически отправлялся `index2`, соответствующий select'у.**

К примеру, я включаю "Технические работы", все остальное отключаю. В поле `index2` в таблице должно записаться "2".

Таблица выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста какими способами это можно  реализовать.

Comment: Напишите PHP код, который будет принимать get index, index2 и записывать в базу. Потом используйте jQuery.ajax для отправки запроса на этот обработчик при событии change поля select. PROFIT

Comment: Почему для выбора вкл/выкл вы используете селекты, а не чекбоксы? Почему в базе вы храните строки, а не числа для полей pay, orders, news и other? С вашей постановкой задачи поля pay, orders, news и other вовсе не нужны, может, отказаться от них совсем?

Comment: Потому что эти строки выводятся в таблицу на странице. И для оператора, который будет с этим работать, слова выглядят нагляднее чем цифры. Как в базе хранить цифры, а выводить строки - я пока придумать не могу. Да и как дать понять index2, что выбран конкретный селект/чекбокс тоже не знаю.

Comment: Все нормальные бд хранят цифры, а не слова. К сожалению, вижу вопрос от Вас каждый день и даю развернутый ответ, но не вижу никакого стремления самостоятельно понять принципы работы моих решений. Пожалуй, мой первый комментарий можно воспринимать как ответ, с помощью которого решается задача.

Comment: Я сначала пробую разобраться сам потом лезу в гугл и если действительно не могу ничего сделать-задаю вопрос здесь.С тем, чем вы мне помогали ранее,я разобрался,пытался сделать тут по такому же принципу как и прошлую таблицу,но не вышло.Хотел сделать вторую таблицу с id типов и их состоянием,но понял,что тут так не прокатит,потому что 4 селекта и это все усложняет.Вам спасибо большое,вы очень помогаете,а я действительно стараюсь. Просто сложно мне,я занимаюсь этим всем всего 5 недель.Тут еще и половина кода - чужого, и он далек от хорошего.Чтобы в него свой внедрить приходится много париться.

Comment: Предлагаю использовать radio button в вашем интерфейсе и всего одно поле index2 в БД. Этого будет достаточно для решения вашей задачи. При выводе таблицы оператору отображать слова вместо цифр, подозреваю, будет следующим вопросом.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответы, буду разбираться. Постараюсь вас больше не доставать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Храню в базе цифры:

```
<select size=1 name=pay>
    <option value="1">Включен</option>
    <option value="0">Выключен</option>
</select>

<select size=1 name=orders>
    <option value="2">Включен</option>
    <option value="0">Выключен</option>
</select>

<select size=1 name=news>
    <option value="3">Включен</option>
    <option value="0">Выключен</option>
</select>

<select size=1 name=other>
    <option value="4">Включен</option>
    <option value="0">Выключен</option>
</select>
```

На страницу вывожу слова, с помощью запроса:

```
SELECT p.type_condition AS `pay`, o.type_condition AS `orders`, n.type_condition AS `news`,
     a.type_condition AS `other`, s.login AS `login`, s.telephone AS `telephone`, 
     s.index AS `index`
FROM
    `vixen_erps_services_sms` s
LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` p
ON
    p.type_id = s.pay
LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` o
ON
    o.type_id = s.orders
LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` n
ON
    n.type_id = s.news
LEFT JOIN
    `vixen_erps_services_type` a
ON
    a.type_id = s.other
```